# wordpress page builder not showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can no longer see my page builder option for both visual composer and siteOrigin page builder after an update to wordPress 4.9.6... No option to switch to page builder, and no option to select backend editor/ frontend editor

I get this errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: hide_shortcode_panel is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (smps-admin-script.js:11)
at i (load-scripts.php:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php:2)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bs_component_show_hide_button' of undefined
    at QTags.i.getButton (load-scripts.php:460)
    at ToolsetCommon.BootstrapCssComponentsQuickTags.self.add_bootstrap_components_buttons (toolset-bs-component-buttons.js:108)
    at toolset-bs-component-buttons.js:21
    at d (toolset-event-manager.min.js:1)
    at Object.j [as doAction] (toolset-event-manager.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (toolset-bs-component-events.js:213)
    at Function.each (load-scripts.php:2)
    at toolset-bs-component-events.js:209
    at load-scripts.php:466

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: Do you any errors in the console? Please provide more informations in order to helping you.

Comment: Hi @Aurélien i just updated the question, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, the problem was due to a plugin short code generator... It seems after the WordPress update there were some codes that were not compatible with the plugin and hence the error. i uninstalled the plugin and the page builder was good.

Thanks again for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

[image]We've got an easy workaround for that:
**Install Classic Editor plugins**

Log in to your installation, go to Dashboard > Plugins and click Add New.

Then, on the search field look for Classic Editor from WordPress Contributors
Link=>
https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/

Comment: This worked great and actually solved another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue lately and I hope my experience can help someone.

Working on a single-page site, suddenly the Page Builder doesn't come up in editor.
Other javascripts were not working, so I tried disabling some plugins: first Yeast SEO and editor turned back on, but after some days, it was gone. Days after I had to disable more and more plugins (PopupMaker, CF7...) to edit the page, then re-enable them after saving.

It was unbearable so I tried to create a new page, importing the "homepage" structure (a VERY useful feature of Siteorigin's Page Builder)... and in this cloned page the builder worked fine also in next edits!

Then it wasn't becouse of content nor plugins. I focused on **revisions**: there were over 600 revs for the homepage. It shouldn't be a problem in the editor, but I couldn't see any other difference.

Installed **WP-Optimize** plugin and cleared revisions. The builder is'n giving any problem anymore.